# How can i add multiselect dropdown checkbox on modal?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

This is my code. I'm trying to add a multiselect checkbox on top of the modal, but it looks different because of the modal.
I tried this in many ways. While working on a normal page, it works distorted on the modal

[![distorted][1]][1]

this is what should be
[![normally][2]][2]

```js
$(function() {
  $('#managedBY').multiselect({
    nonSelectedText: 'Select Your Manager(s)',
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    buttonWidth: '430px'
  });
  $('#prim_skills_form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var
      form_data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      data: form_data,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#managedBY option:selected').each(function() {
          $(this).prop('selected', false);
        });
        $('#managedBY').multiselect('refresh');
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="modaledit{{row.userid}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Please Update User</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="{{url_for('Admin.update')}}" method="POST" id="prim_skills_form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select your Manager(s)</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="managedBY" name="managedBY" multiple>
              {% for row in users %} {% if row.role == 'admin' %}
              <option value="{{row.managerid}}">{{row.managerid}} - {{row.name}}</option>
              {%endif%} {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Looks css problem to me. You must be having different styles corresponding to modal which is getting applied to dropdown.

Comment: I am guessing this is probably because the `modal` class applies `display: none`, and so it probably either doesn't find the element, or can't read element dimensions, when you try to initialize the `multiselect`.